# POST request returns index.html doc instead of json data in react js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After deploying my react CRUD app to cpanel, the POST request on a dynamic router

```
<Route exact path="/product/:code">
  <SingleProduct/> 
</Route>
```

is now returning index.html instead of json data from the request. I'm getting 200 status code but the response is html. However, it works fine locally. Am using php as the backend.All the non dynamic routes are working except this one. what can id do to fix this?

This is the ajax.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
xhr.open('POST', backend.php,true);   
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  
xhr.onload = function(){ 
  const users =JSON.parse(this.responseText); console.log(users);    
  dispatch(fetchperfumes(users))
} 
xhr.send(`result=${result}`);
```

---

This is the php code.

```
if(isset($_POST['result'])){
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM products'; 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);  
  echo json_encode($users);
}
```

---

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question first of all. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Hello, please fix your formatting, it's unreadable. Thank you

Comment: sorry, did the formating . i think its readable now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. When i did  debugging in my browser network, i found out the request header path for dynamic route was :

---

```
 product/backend.php
```

---

instead of

---

```
 backend.php
```

---

To solve this i had to include the domain name in the path

---

```
 https://something.something/backend
```